# I want to use glm function for 1000 datasets

Tags: loops, replication, simulation, boot, glm

I am trying to create 1000 datasets each having 4 variables, X1 is normal(0,1), X2 is normal(0,1), X3 is expit(0.5X1 + 0.8X2), and A is Bernouli(X3). All variables have 2500 observations.

I wanted to fit each of the 1000 datasets into glm model with no avail.

That's what I did

```
 sim_list = replicate(n =3,
                     expr = {data.frame(X1 = X1 <- rnorm(2500, mean = 0, sd = 1), X2 = X2 <- rnorm(2500, mean = 0, sd = 1), X3 = X3 <- rnorm(2500, mean = 0, sd = 1), X4 = X4 <- expit(0.5*X1 + 0.8*X3), A = A <- rbern(2500, X4)},
                     simplify = F)

for (i in 1:3){
glm1[i] <- glm(A~X1, family = binomial, data = sim_list[[i]])
score[i] <- glm1[i]$fitted.values
}
```

I really would appreciate some help with this

Comment: Your `for` loop looks fine, but your `sim_list` doesn't. One issue is the double assignments (you have both `=` and `<-` but can only use one for each variable, I think).

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael pointed out, you cannot do double assignment, use either `<-` or `=` , not both. Inside replicate, you try to create a dataframe column that is conditional `X4 = expit(0.5*X1 + 0.8*X3)` on a column that doesn't exist (yet). So this will not work. We first make the function work:

```
library(simcausal)
library(locfit)

func = function(){
                    X1 = rnorm(2500, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
                    X2 = rnorm(2500, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
                    X3 = rnorm(2500, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
                    X4 = expit(0.5*X1 + 0.8*X3)
                    A = rbern(2500, X4)
                    data.frame(X1,X2,X3,X4,A)
}
```

The function `func()` now works:

```
head(func())
            X1         X2          X3        X4 A
1 -0.316250388  1.7826809 -0.57710388 0.3498251 1
2 -0.140362056 -0.1895857  0.66395833 0.6132480 1
3 -0.008822927 -0.8104381 -0.57667306 0.3856227 0
4  1.053421856  1.5677077 -1.92307184 0.2666382 1
5 -0.142992075  0.3378479  1.13319243 0.6974233 1
6 -1.502032980 -0.3575286 -0.02838796 0.3156735 0
```

We create the sim_list:

```
sim_list <- replicate(n =3,func(),simplify = F)
```

Now comes another important part, you need to create a list to store your results, and you assign them using double square brackets `[[` :

```
glm1 <- vector("list",3)
score <- vector("list",3)

for (i in 1:3){
glm1[[i]] <- glm(A~X1, family = binomial, data = sim_list[[i]])
score[[i]] <- glm1[[i]]$fitted.values
}
```